# python MNIST dataset "no attribute train_images"

Tags: python, mnist

I'm using python3.7 and trying to use MNIST train data images.
**Instead of using** PyTorch, tf, kears framwork which help to use dataset easily, I tried using mnist module directly.

I was following [a tutorial](https://victorzhou.com/blog/intro-to-cnns-part-1/) for CNN, there was

```
import mnist
```

Then I tried "pip install python-mnist" (after uninstall python-mnist, I 've done 'pip install mnist') and it was downloaded successfully.
then I typed same codes to make train images.

train_images = mnist.train_images()

**however it says "AttributeError: module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'"**

I checked print(mnist) and it gives the path, 
but print(mnist.train_images) gives same error message.
As far as I know, it is possible to use functions in '**init**.py', but it doesn't seem to.. or what am I getting wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqW59.png)

++ furthermore, even if I deleted mnist folder, and run the same code, it still exists printing out the same path, which I believe it's supposed to print 'there is no module mnist' .. what kind of knowledge am I missing now..? :(

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Looks like you installed the wrong package. [python-mnist](https://pypi.org/project/python-mnist/) != [mnist](https://pypi.org/project/mnist/)

Comment: @G.Anderson I also tried pip install mnist .. :((I forgot to mention it and now edited the question!)

Comment: Just deleting the folder doesn't necessarily uninstall, you should pip uninstall both packages and reinstall only the one that actually has the function you're tring to use

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you. one more curious thing please. why is mnist module object still alive even if I delete that folder? ( you can see the pics in my question article)

Comment: Just because you delete the folder does not mean that python _knows_ that the module has been deleted. Behind the scenes, a lot more goes into installing a library on the PATH than just creating a folder full of files (registering dependencies, etc)

Comment: @G.Anderson actually I used pip uninstall mnist and also checked the message saying there's nothing to uninstall when I tried 'pip uninstall mnist'! I think there's something connected..  but anyway I got what you wanted to say :) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you just need to follow the instruction on the Github page of MNIST ([link](https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist)).
After installing the lib with `pip install python-mnist`, you should clone the repo and execute a script to download the mnist data:

```
git clone https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist
cd python-mnist
./get_data.sh
```

You data will be saved in a folder named `data`, after that you can call it in code using:

```py
from mnist import MNIST
mndata = MNIST('data/')
mndata.gz = False
images, labels = mndata.load_training()
```

The `images` variable is a list of lists of pixels, you should reshape it after that to see the images.

**NB**: If I were you, I will just use `pytorch` or `Keras` because is a lot easier and they do the job for you. After that, if you dont want to use tensors, you can just convert them back to numpy arrays.

> Also note if you have a file `./mnist.py` in your local folder, then this will take over and prevent you from importing the desired `mnist` library.

Comment: thank you I confused with python-mnist and mnist. But why it doesn't work when I did as 1)  git clone https://github.com/datapythonista/mnist    2) import mnist ?

Comment: in fact if you do just `import mnist`, to call the function you should use `mndata = mnist.MNIST('data/')` because `MNIST` is a part of `mnist`

Answer (score 1):

just use
\\\
\\\\

```
from mnist import *

x_train=train_images()

y_train=train_labels()
```