# AttributeError: module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'

Tags: python, attributeerror, mnist

I was reproducing the Video from freecodecamp.org [YouTube - 2:50:00](https://stackoverflow.com)

The teacher is using colab.research. His Code is as follows:

```
!pip install pillow mnist numpy sklearn

from PIL import Image
import mnist
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# training variables
x_train = mnist.train_images()
y_train = mnist.train_labels()
```

When He is doing that, there is no problem at all. But I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b693104c2566> in <module>()
      1 # training variables
----> 2 x_train = mnist.train_images()

AttributeError: module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'
```

If I try the same thing on Pycharm, I dont have any issues with train_images() but a different one:

> raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the " EOFError:
> Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

I tried to find a solution using google stackoverflow etc. No Success :(

Edit:

I checked the **init**.py inside of mnist and I can find the train_images() there:

```
def train_images():
    """Return train images from Yann LeCun MNIST database as a numpy array.
    Download the file, if not already found in the temporary directory of
    the system.

    Returns
    -------
    train_images : numpy.ndarray
        Numpy array with the images in the train MNIST database. The first
        dimension indexes each sample, while the other two index rows and
        columns of the image
    """
    return download_and_parse_mnist_file('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')


def test_images():
    """Return test images from Yann LeCun MNIST database as a numpy array.
    Download the file, if not already found in the temporary directory of
    the system.

    Returns
    -------
    test_images : numpy.ndarray
        Numpy array with the images in the train MNIST database. The first
        dimension indexes each sample, while the other two index rows and
        columns of the image
    """
    return download_and_parse_mnist_file('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
```

Comment: It's most likely your python environment. What virtual environment are you using? If you are using conda, then try creating a new virtual environment before installing the dependencies. If you're using `venv`, try doing the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I dont think that I am using any virtual env. I didnt even know about that. But it feels strange that it is beause of that

Comment: This is most probably the reason why it's throwing these errors. You shouldn't install dependencies like `mnist`, `sklearn`, etc without activating a virtual environment. Otherwise, it'd get really messy. Look for how to use `venv` in python.

Comment: Still the same issue even with environment. But at least it should work with colab.research. Unfortunately its not working. Did you copy and paste the code above? Is it working for you?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103428/python-mnist-dataset-no-attribute-train-images

Comment: maybe you created file `mnist.py` and now `import` loads your file `mnist.py` instead of module `mnist` and it can't find `train_images` in your file. Check `print( mnist.__file__ )` to see which file it imports. And if you have file `mnist.py` or subfolder `mnist` then rename it.

Comment: @furas This is not the problem. It is also not working for google colab.research. Did you copy and paste the code above? Did it work for you?

Comment: I can run it on local computer and Colab and it has no problem to find function `train_images`. But it has other problem - it has to download images (compresed in file `.gz`) from server and server sends `HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable`. And this can give your problem `EOFError`. It could download uncomplete file `.gz` and it can't uncompress it. You may have to wait and try again or you will have to download images manually and put in expected folder.

Comment: BUT this doesn't resolve first problem 
`module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'` because it has to be some file `mnist.py` or subfolder `mnist`. You should check `import mnist` and `print( mnist.__file__ )` to find this file.

Comment: if it has problem to download images then there are alternative places - see: [PyTorch - MNIST server down](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/mnist-server-down/114433/14)

Answer (score 1):

### AttributeError

If you have problem

```
AttributeError: module 'mnist' has no attribute 'train_images'
```

then you have other file `mnist.py` and it import it instead of module `mnist`

You can check what file is imported

```
import mnist

print( mnist.__file__ )
```

and you can open this file in editor to check what you have in this file.

or you can even display with

```
print( open(mnist.__file__).read() )
```

To resolve problem you have to rename this file.

---

### EOFError or HTTP Error 503

If you have problem

```
raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the " EOFError: 
     Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

or

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

then problem can be with server and then you can try to download it from other places

Using Google I found alternative place in `PyTorch forum` in [PyTorch - MNIST server down](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/mnist-server-down/114433/14)

If you change `mnist.datasets_url` then it can download from alternative place

```
#!pip install mnist

import mnist

mnist.datasets_url = 'https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist/'

# training variables
x_train = mnist.train_images()
y_train = mnist.train_labels()

print('x_train:', x_train.shape)
print('y_train:', y_train.shape)
```

And this works for me on local computer and in `Google Colab`.

Answer (score 0):

**For Google Colab**
At the top write `!pip install mnist`.
 Use `import mnist`.
Then simply store the images and labels:

### For Train data usage

```
train_images = mnist.train_images() 
train_labels = mnist.train_labels()
```

### For Test data usage

```
test_images = mnist.test_images()
test_labels = mnist.test_labels()
```

That's it!!!
After that you will be able to import and use **`mnist`** dataset